Добавить произвольный файл в реквизит
Добавляется строка в табличную часть, где один из реквизитов должен принимать файл (скорее ссылку на файл во временном хранилище). Помогите разобраться с НачатьПомещениеФайлаНаСервер, не могу понять как это реализовывать.
Так же не видит этот самый реквизит через табличную часть (объект.список.файл) - выдает ошибку при попытке заполнить через Имя = 123; объект.список.файл = Имя;.
Я совсем новичок в 1С, так что в терминологии могу не все понять

Опиши саму задачу, что вам требуется.
